# gettext django - Why do I still have the name from msgstr?

Tags: django

**settings.py:**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'
ugettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext(u'English')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(DIRNAME, '../locale'),
    )
```

**templates/index.html:**

```
{% load i18n l10n %}
{% trans "Hund" %}
```

**locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:**

```
#: projectname/templates/index.html:2
msgid "Hund"
msgstr "Dog"
```

Why do I still have the name of: `msgstr` - "Dog"? (Regardless of whether I set English or German in `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'`)

Answer (score 1):

What do you have **locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po** file?

Maybe be in both languages you have msgstr "Dog"?

Answer (score 0):

When I removed this middleware everything started working properly:

```
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
```